# Foundation CSS Framework dropdown select

Tags: css, select, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation CSS.
But the dropdown select I use as a simple HTML tag.

The problem is that dropdown is not working on small (mobile) windows.

I reproduced the error here http://jsfiddle.net/BZrT8/1/ (in CSS block I added both foundation.css and main.css I use).

I found that the problem is caused by the `float:left;` property of `.row .mobile-three` property in **foundation.css**

Any ideas why `float:left;` makes the dropdown list not working? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a div that overlaps your select on narrow screens:

```
<div class="seven columns"></div>
```

You can't see it, cause it doesn't have a content or background. It floats to the right and occupies the space; since it's later in DOM it's over your select.

Remove this div or reposition/refloat it out of your way.